# Is it "take the pillow off your bed" or "take the pillow from your bed"?

Tags: phrasal-verbs, collocations

Could you tell which of the following sentences sounds correct and natural?

> Please **take** the pillow **off** your bed and put it on the floor.
>
> Please **take** the pillow **from** your bed and put it on the floor.

What I'm trying to say is that I want the person to remove the pillow from their bed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are both fine, and idiomatically they can mean the same thing, but "take the pillow off the bed" is more instructional and in line with the subsequent instruction to "put it" elsewhere.

"The pillow *from* the bed" could be a description of where the pillow comes from, and while it can mean that the pillow is currently on the bed it doesn't necessarily mean that. For example, if I travelled to the Ukraine and brought a bottle of Vodka back home to England, I might refer to that bottle as "the vodka from the Ukraine". With the vodka sitting on my table in England, I might then say "take the vodka from the Ukraine and put it in the cupboard".